# Flash Slider Component With Decimal Value?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, slider, decimal

how do i set up a Flash CS5 Slider component to trace decimal values, from 0.00 to 10.00 when the slider is dragged?  i can't seem to find where i need to set these options to permit decimals.

is it possible to set this in ActionScript?

[image]

Comment: i'm guessing the component only works with integers, and that decimals are conceived by the developer only?  so if i want 0.00 to 10.00, i need to set my component max value to 1000 and trace(slider.value / 100); ?

Comment: this way isn't a complete solution, since redundant zeros will be automatically removed, so while 2.34 will remain 2.34, 2.30 will become 2.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps there is a more formal way of accomplishing this, but i've managed to solve this problem by creating a custom string format method.

first, since i want my values to range from 0.00 to 10.00, i set the slider component to have 0 as the minimum value and 1000 as the maximum value.  these values will be divided by 100 for the decimal.

```
//in the slider change event handler method
trace(formatCycleTextString(mySlider.value));

//custom format method
function formatCycleTextString(value:Number):String
    {
    var resultString:String = String(value / 100);

    switch  (resultString.length)
            {
            case 1: resultString = resultString.concat(".00");  break;
            case 2: resultString = resultString.concat(".00");  break;
            case 3: resultString = resultString.concat("0");
            }

    return resultString;
    }
```